# SQL Update of One Table from Another Database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 MySQL databases - named 'basemodel' and 'TRAK'.

I wish to set some values in TRAK to the values of specific columns in basemodel.

I tried the following:

```
UPDATE TRAK.Argument t
SET 
t.`object ID`= basemodel.t_object.Object_ID, 
t.`AD exchange element owning ID`= basemodel.t_object.ea_guid,
t.`argument description` = basemodel.t_object.Note


FROM  basemodel.t_object
WHERE basemodel.t_object.Stereotype ='Argument'
```

but MySQL returns an error to the effect that there is an error in syntax near 'FROM basemodel.t_object'. I know from the auto-complete on the SQL tool that \ the column exists so clearly I've made some sort of typo nearby.

A typical subset of the data in basemodel.t_object is:

```
Object_ID,Object_Type,Diagram_ID,Name,Author,Note,Stereotype
1893,Text,230,5.4 Architecture Viewpoints :MV-03 Section 5.4 Architecture Viewpoints - Requirements,Nic Plum,,
1894,Class,0,A TRAK-conforming architecture view meets the requirement to include identifying and supplementary information.,Nic Plum,,Claim
1895,Class,0,A TRAK-conforming architecture view is required to include a version number for the view.,Nic Plum,,Argument
1896,Text,0,,Nic Plum,,
1897,Class,0,"TRAK states that the version of TRAK against which the architecture description (view set) was produced may be stated and that if it isn't stated it is assumed that the latest (current) current version of the TRAK specification set (TRAK, Metamodel and Vi",Nic Plum,,Argument
1898,Class,0,"TRAK defines a viewpoint numbering convention - every TRAK viewpoint has a 'Vp' in its identifier which is preceded by the first letter of the TRAK perspective that the viewpoint belongs to.",Nic Plum,,Argument
1899,Class,0,"TRAK defines a view identification convention. Every TRAK view can be identified by the first letter of the TRAK perspective that the view belongs to followed by a 'V' e.g. SV-01, MV-02. If further differentiation is needed from other frameworks a namespa",Nic Plum,,Argument
1900,Class,0,A TRAK view is able to identify its governing viewpoint through the view identifier because the viewpoint and view have corresponding identifiers e.g. MVp-02 (Architecture Description Design Record Viewpoint) vs MV-02 (Architecture Description Design Reco,Nic Plum,,Argument
1901,Artifact,0,Viewpoint Identification,Nic Plum,,Evidence
1902,Class,0,The tuples in a TRAK viewpoint define a subset of the TRAK metamodel that addresses the concerns framed by the viewpoint.  A TRAK viewpoint is selected by the architect based on the concerns it frames (addresses).,Nic Plum,,Argument
1903,Artifact,0,Viewpoint Selection,Nic Plum,,Evidence
1904,Class,0,"TRAK defines an element in its metamodel that is used to represent an issue. It is called a 'Concern'. It can be related to any object within the TRAK metamodel using the 'Concern about ...' tuple. ",Nic Plum,,Argument
1905,Class,0,"The 'Concern about' tuple is a universal tuple. It is defined as an optional tuple in every TRAK viewpoint allowing a Concern to be added to every TRAK view. ",Nic Plum,,Argument
1906,Artifact,0,TRAK Metamodel - Concern,Nic Plum,,Evidence
1907,Class,0,"The 'Concern about [element]' is a mandatory tuple for the MVp-02 Architecture Description Design Record Viewpoint and therefore is mandatory for a conforming TRAK architecture description.",Nic Plum,,Argument
1908,Note,0,,Nic Plum,,
1909,Text,0,,Nic Plum,,
```

The table TRAK.Argument is empty.

It has the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `Argument` (
  `object ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AD exchange element owning ID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AD exchange element owning organisation` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AD exchange element recipient element name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL',
  `AD exchange element recipient element ID` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AD exchange element recipient organisation` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AD exchange element external reference` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AD exchange element reference URL` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL',
  `pm national caveat` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pm codeword` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pm descriptor` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pm marking` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pm commercial` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pm marking owner` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `element URI` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reference URL` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rationale` longtext,
  `argument ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `argument description` longtext,
  `submission date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `acceptance date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` longtext COMMENT ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`object ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: It isn't clear what the relationship between the tables `TRAK.Argument` and `basemodel.t_object` is to be.  [MySQL's multi-table update join syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) does not use a `FROM` clause. If you post a sample from the two tables involved together with a sample of what you intend the query result to be, we can assist you in getting the syntax right. As it is right now, nothing from `Argument` is referenced in the `WHERE` so all its rows would be updated.

Comment: OK. Please see table structure / data above.